# Eclipse Egit. Checkout creates new commit. Why?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

As I understand GIT, when I checkout on commit, I should get its files copy in my work directory, but no new commit should appear. Though **when I use EGit and checkout on commit I see new commit in reflog. Why?** As I understand checkout should not create new commit. Right?

Here I right click on commit and choose checkout

[image]

Then I get new commit in reflog:

[image]

So now I have few commits in my local master, but I never asked to do them.

Git integration for Eclipse - Task focused interface  **4.6.1.201703071140-r**    org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group    Eclipse EGit

Comment: You may be working by mistake with the _Git Reflog_ view instead of the _History_ view (see also [git reflog](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-reflog)).

Comment: @howlger the problem is history view is empty, so I not have an option of using it. That is why I think reflog is the only way to see my commits history on branch. Do you have and idea why history is empty?

Comment: You have to tell the _History_ view which history should be shown, e. g. in _Git Repositories_ view right-click a repository and choose: _Show In > History_. In the _History_ view the option **_Show All Branches and Tags_ (upper right button) should be enabled** (otherwise you will see only commit of the current branch).

Comment: Thanks! It works. It is was not obvious for me that I should use Show In > History option on a branch. If you would add the answer I will accept it. The other my question you marked duplication actually is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **work with the *History* view instead of with the *Git Reflog* view** (see [git reflog](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-reflog) and [toniedzwiedz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46110851/6505250) for details):

1. Tell the History view which history should be shown: e. g. **in *Git Repositories*** view **right-click** a repository and choose: ***Show In > History***.
2. In the *History* view **enable the option *Show All Branches and Tags*** (right button in the view toolbar). Otherwise, only commits of the current branch are displayed.

Answer (score 2):

You don't see a new commit in the reflog. What you see is an updated position of HEAD. You changed it to commit `4b0d96a` when you checked it out. When you check out another commit, branch or a tag, you'll see yet another entry appear in the reflog.

Try switching between two branches repeatedly and you'll see the same two commit hashes appended to the reflog again and again. This does not mean you're creating new commits. You just see existing commits being logged as recent commits pointed to by the `HEAD` pointer.

From the [git reflog docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog):

> This command manages the information recorded in the reflogs.
>
> The "show" subcommand (which is also the default, in the absence of any subcommands) shows the log of the reference provided in the command-line (or `HEAD`, by default). The reflog covers all recent actions, and in addition the `HEAD` reflog records branch switching. `git reflog show` is an alias for `git log -g --abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline;` see [`git-log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) for more information.

You may also find this [chapter of the *Pro Git* book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_git_reflog) interesting. It offers a more comprehensible description of what `git reflog` does.

Comment: You probably right here, but I not see the other way to see my commits history. The history view is empty. Is there a way to see whatever history or reflog with my commits, instead of "Updated position of HEAD" messed with commits?

Comment: I suspect this has to do with Eclipse rather than Git itself. Can you post a screeenshot of the _History_ tab? Maybe it's a matter of resizing some UI elements or a bug in the IDE? I haven't used Eclipse in years so no obvious reason comes to my mind straight away. What you can try is open a terminal, navigate to the location of your local Git repository and use a `git log` to make sure this isn't a problem with Git itself.

Comment: Thanks your answer was helpful. I found the way to use history view with help of @howlger comment.